# What you recommend for Electron Notification?

Tags: electron

I am looking for recommendation to show Electron Notifications. Electron provides Notification API but did not find that helpful. Is there any way to show some Toast notification in Electron main window itself rather showing Windows/System Notification ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some thing like https://notifyjs.jpillora.com/ , This shows notification inside the main window, 
Electrons API's for notification can be used for desktop notifications only.

Comment: Is there node module of this notifyjs ?